# Passing new DOM Elements via Socketio

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

How can i pass DOM Elements server-side via socketio to display new message content.

```js
// Client

// Pass DOM element as string 
function elemToString(elem){
    return elem.outerHTML
}

window.addEventListener("keyup", sendMessage, false);
function sendMessage(key) {
 if (key.keyCode === 13) {
  if (chatbox.value !== "") {
   const child = document.createElement("div");
   child.textContent = `${chatbox.value}`
   child.className = "messages"
   chat.appendChild(child);
   socket.emit('chatMsg', elemToString(child))
            chatbox.value = "";
   chatbox.style.display = "none";
   setTimeout(()=>{
    child.remove()
   },4000)
  } 
  else chatbox.style.display = "none";
 }
}


// User Class

class User {
    constructor(name, x, y) {
        this.alive = false
        this.name = name
        this.cells = []
        this.room = 'none'
        this.message = []
    }

    update(cells) {
        this.cells = cells
    }
}

module.exports = User

// Server

socket.on('chatMsg', elem => {
    user.message.push(elem)
})
```

I have a hotkey which sends new divs which display message content. I want to pass the data server-side via socket.io so all users can see new message content instead of just the individual client.

Answer (score 0):

The first question I would ask is whether you really need to pass around HTML or DOM objects? Based on the above snippet, it appears that sending the messages as strings (without any HTML markup, just the message body) is by far the easiest way for both the server and the chat client(s). As to sending the message to all users in the chat room, this feature is already built into socket.io (see https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) and unless you need to implement custom logging or filtering, you could just use it out of the box

There are several ways you could go about building this chat server:

#### Simple / POC approach

If you just want to have a quick prototype and see if it does what you want it to do, and you are not too concerned with auditing, logging, filtering etc., then:

- When the client connects, it "joins" a socket.io "room" (the name of the room could match the room on the client or you may choose to format/hash it etc.)
- All chat room clients send events to that same room and listen to the events emitted by that room. The socket.io backend takes care of re-broadcasting the events, so you would not need to do anything
- To send message to the room, the "sender" client would broadcast a well known event, something like `{ message: '<<message text>>' }`. All clients listen to events in the room, and once a new event arrives they create a new HTML element (say, a `<div>`) with that message as content and append it to the chat window

This should cover the basic chat room scenario

#### A bit more involved chat server

In the real-world implementations, we typically want to have a bit more control over what events can and cannot be broadcasted (for example, we want to have the ability to silence a chatter or filter profanity/abusive language etc.) In this case, we cannot simply use blind broadcast, so typically the client would use two socket.io channels - a "room" for incoming messages and a direct channel for outgoing.

In this scenario, the server acts as a bridge - it listens to the incoming messages, does all the necessary filtering, preprocessing, sanitizes the messages to prevent injections etc., and then broadcasts the resulting message in the room. In this scenario:

- All chat clients subscribe to the same "incoming message" room, just like in the previous scenario
- When the chatter needs to send a message (say, they hit Enter), the client socket emits an event to the server and tells it which room this message is intended for (e.g. `{ incoming_message: 'xyz', user: 'username', room: 'room_21' }`
- The server receives the message and processes it (for example, checks the username against the list of banned users), then broadcasts the processed message in the room specified in the original message. The other chat participants receive the message and render it

In this scenario, you can keep the history of every message sent by a particular user (much like you do in your code snippet)

This link (https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements) has a few examples on sending and broadcasting arbitrary JSON messages and also shows working with channels etc.

Hope that helps and good luck with your chat server!